# How to change the order in which files are listed by bash

Tags: bash, filenames

I have some files. When I list them I get the order:

```
frame0001i0002.png
frame0001.png
frame0002i0003.png
frame0002.png
frame0003i0004.png
frame0003.png
frame0004.png
frame0005.png
frame0006.png
```

I had assumed that `frame0001.png` would come before `frame0001i0002.png`, because I need to operate on them in the order:

```
frame0001.png
frame0001i0002.png
frame0002.png
frame0002i0003.png
frame0003.png
frame0003i0004.png
frame0004.png
frame0005.png
frame0006.png
```

Do I need to rename them to appear in the order that I want?

---

Ultimately I want to change their names to:

```
frame0001.png
frame0002.png
frame0003.png
frame0004.png
frame0005.png
frame0006.png
frame0007.png
frame0008.png
frame0009.png
```

and in the order from the cell above.

Comment: What are you using to list them? If I `cd` to the parent directory and run `for file in *.png; do echo "${file##*/}"; done` it lists them in the desired order.

Comment: Likewise using [`find`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) and a `while` loop to create an array. E.g. `files=(); while read -rd ''; do files+=("${REPLY}"); done < <(find . -name '*.png' -print0)` - each file/member in the array is indexed  in the desired order. You can check by subsequently running `declare -p files`, or `printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"` to list them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You encounter this problem because `i` comes before `.` in your default sort order.

Using the following you can get the expected order :

```
sort -t'.' -k 1,1
```

This defines `.` is a field separator and that we should only consider the first field (the part before the extention) for the sort order. We're now comparing `frame0001` with `frame0001i0002`, and the shortest will be printed first.

Answer (score 1):

ls can also do this with `-v` option

```
$ ls -vw1 *png
frame0001.png
frame0001i0002.png
frame0002.png
frame0002i0003.png
frame0003.png
frame0003i0004.png
frame0004.png
frame0005.png
frame0006.png
```

From `ls` help

```
$ ls --help
...
  -v                         natural sort of (version) numbers within text
  -w, --width=COLS           set output width to COLS.  0 means no limit
...
```